# Mapping list to list in Dozer

Tags: java, xml, list, mapping, dozer

```
List<CustomerData> mapAddress(List<Address> addressList){

   List<Customer> customerData = new ArrayList<Customer>();

   if( CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty( addressList ) ){
        for( Address address : addressList )
        {
            customerData.add( this.dozerBeanMapper.map( address, Customer.class ) );
        }
   }
   return customerData;
}
```

**CustomerData.java**:

```
Has instance field 'address' of type String
```

**Address.java**

```
Has instance field 'mainLocation' of type String
```

Currently I am using for loop to map each object of Address with Customer, how can I directly map **addressList** with **customerData** (list to list)  without looping.  Can someone please help me with the xml file changes for this logic.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember there was no possibility to map a Collection to a Collection in Dozer. You need to iterate over it. Take a look at this closed issue and the reason: https://github.com/DozerMapper/dozer/issues/5

What you could do to ease the pain would be using Java 8 (if you can) or Guava for some more declarative way of handling that mapping.

Java 8 example:

```
<FROM, TO> List<TO> mapList(List<FROM> fromList, final Class<TO> toClass) {
    return fromList
            .stream()
            .map(from -> this.dozerBeanMapper.map(from, toClass))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Guava example:

```
<FROM, TO> List<TO> mapList(List<FROM> fromList, final Class<TO> toClass) {
    return Lists.transform(fromList, new Function<FROM, TO>() {
        @Override
        public TO apply(FROM from) {
            return this.dozerBeanMapper(from, toClass);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info...actually I saw dozer docs.. http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/collectionandarraymapping.html 
There they mentioned its possible, I am trying to understand it but I am not able to..

Comment: Yes, I've seen that. But notice that the list mapping is specified on ``<field>`` level and not on ``<mapping>``. Which means that it'll work for list fields in a class. What you could also do is create a wrapper class with the list which than would be automatically mapped to another wrapper with list field. If you would like to map it automatically to a list I think that own dozer converter would be required.

Comment: yeah got you.., I am trying to use the java 8 example, you have mentioned above, its giving the  error method toList() is undefined

Comment: statically imported ```Collectors.toList()```. Also edited in the response.

Comment: ok..is there any advantage to prefer this java 8 approach rather using general for loop (which I have written in the code) ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think this could be useful, thanks @gmaslowski for the idea:

```
/**
 * @param <T>
 * @param <V>
 * @param fromList list source objects
 * @param toClass target class objects
 * @param mapperId map-id in to dozer-mapping file 
 * @return list of toClass mapped 
 */
public <T, V> List<V> mapList(List<T> fromList, Class<V> toClass, String mapperId) {
    return fromList.stream().map(from -> {
        try {
            return this.dozerBean.getObject().map(from, toClass, mapperId);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error Dozer Mapping Objects {}", e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```